# Typecast an uint32 number to a struct pointer?

Tags: c

While working with C, I have encountered some code which typecast an uint32 number to struct pointer, I can not evaluate if this is right or wrong, could you guys help me about this?

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32 a;
    //some other element;
} StructA;

int main()
{
    StructA *a;
    uint32 b;
    b = //assign a value for b;
    a = (StructA*)b;
}
```

Is this type of casting b to pointer of StructA correct? And please explain to me why this is right or wrong, thank you so much for your help

Comment: You need to consider `64bit` machines where address can be of size `8bytes`.

Comment: *I can not evaluate if this is right or wrong*  It might "work", but there are no guarantees, and if it does work it's because, on that particular implementation, `struct` pointers happen to fit into `uint32` values (assuming that's an unsigned 32-bit `int`) and nothing else goes wrong, such as alignment.  Port that code to 64-bit, though, where pointers **won't** fit into a 32-bit `int` of any type, and it will fail.  It's bad code at best, utterly wrong and completely broken at worst.

Comment: only `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` can be safely cast to and from pointers

Comment: @phuclv Note however that [`intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional types](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4).

Comment: There are reason one would assign an integer to a pointer, and they, and the correctness of the code, are dependent on the situation and the compiler and computing platform. You need to show the code on the right-hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing is to convert an integer to a pointer type. This is what the language has to say about such a conversion:

> **[6.3.2.3 Pointers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3)**
>   ...
>   [5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5). An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

So you have to look up the documentation of the implementation (i.e. the compiler) to see if this is allowed. Note that this code is not portable and may well result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have encounterd some code which typecase an uint32 number to struct pointer
```

The address of the first member of a `struct` and the `struct` itself are interchangeable:

```
void foo(uint32 *u)
{
    ((StructA *)u)->a = 10;
}

StructA t;
foo((uint32 *)&t);
```

But this doesn't mean that you can use a concrete type to initialize a `struct`, in your case:

```
a = (StructA*)b;
```

you are using an integer to initialize a pointer, in consequence `a` points to garbage (some random address).

There is no problem in doing that:

```
a = (StructA*)&b; // notice the address-of operator
```

because `a` and `b` haves the same align requirements and they are interchangeable, but then, trying to access to `a->someOtherElement` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain? maybe this doesn't answer the question, but at least tell whats wrong

Comment: Perhaps someone do not like the question and DV all answers too ? For me you perfectly answers the question (and I UV it)

Answer (score -1):

In the general case, converting a value from an integral type to a pointer and dereferencing the pointer only makes sense when those both conditions are true:

- the architecture allows the integral type to represent the value of a pointer
- the value was obtained from the address of a struct of same type.

For example on a 32 bit architecture, this is legal C:

```
StructA *a;
StructA other {};
uint32_t b;
...
b = (uint32_t) &other;
a = (StructA*) b;
```

The other valid use case is even more constraining. Some architecture may have specific *registers* mapped at well known addresses. In that case, this is also legal:

```
StructA *a;
StructA other {};
uint32_t b;
...
b = (uint32_t) ...;  // well known address on a specific machine and a specific compiler
a = (StructA*) b;
```

The requirements are:

- the machine has specific *registers* starting at that well known address
- the specific implementation maps those registers to a struct of type `*StructA`, with no padding problems

Comment: Can you explain to me why we need a = (StructA*) b here? As above code b = (uint32_t) &other assign address of other to b so I think that a = b is enough. Please correct me if I wrong

Comment: @HoàngKhánh: A decent compiler should emit a warning for *assigning from integer to pointer whitout a cast*. And best practices recommend to avoid warnings...